# What is the Rao-Cramer inequality of $ f(x;)= e^{-(x-)}$?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Find the Rao-Cramer inequality if the random sample 1,2,..., is taken from the distribution with the p.d.f.

$$ f(x;)= e^{-(x-)}$$

where $>$

I am aware of that I need to calculate:

$$ \frac{1}{-n[\frac{d^2}{dθ^2}ln(f(x;θ))]} or \frac{1}{-n[\frac{d}{dθ}ln(f(x;θ))]^2} $$

I calculated log-likelihood as:

$$ lnL = lne^{-θn} + lne^{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} = -θn + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$
$$ \frac{dlnL}{dθ} = -n $$
$$ \frac{d^2lnL}{dθ^2} = -1 $$

Is there a problem with calculations? How can I calculate the lower bound?

Comment: Fisher information is defined for some 'regular' distributions whose support is independent of the parameter. This calculation doesn't hold here naturally.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that this is a pdf for $x>\theta$ and not $x>0$.